# Failed to build vignette with devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)

Tags: r

When I finally need to build up my vignette, I keep getting this error but have no idea about what is going on here.

```
  System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr (last 10 lines):
E> --- failed re-building ‘finalproject_report.Rmd’
E> 
E> --- re-building ‘overview.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
E> --- finished re-building ‘overview.Rmd’
E> 
E> SUMMARY: processing the following files failed:
E>   ‘finalproject_report.Rmd’ ‘finalproject_report.Rmd’
E> 
E> Error: Vignette re-building failed.
E> Execution halted
```

Does anyone have any idea about this? I never run into this before.

Comment: Have you tried using the standard tools instead of devtools?  From the command line, run `R CMD INSTALL pkgdir` where `pkgdir` is the directory holding your package.